# Regex help on multiple lines using Java

Tags: java, regex

I need to parse a BUFKIT weather model file and it's really quite a long file.

```
PRES TMPC TMWC DWPC THTE DRCT SKNT OMEG
CFRL HGHT
995.10 4.64 3.24 1.45 290.15 360.00 0.58 -0.10
0.00 292.82
990.40 5.04 2.18 -1.95 288.49 75.96 4.80 -0.10
0.00 331.43
985.70 6.44 2.36 -3.77 289.24 109.86 7.44 -0.10
0.00 370.34
976.00 8.64 3.43 -4.12 292.23 142.13 8.86 -0.10
0.00 410.44
```

Within the file, I really only care about the lines the numerical lines (which are broken into two lines).  For example, I'd like to parse:

```
995.10 4.64 3.24 1.45 290.15 360.00 0.58 -0.10
0.00 292.82
```

I can find the individual decimals using:

```
-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?
```

I can't figure out how to capture all 10 of them, including the line break.

So what is an expression I can use to parse all 10?

edit:  There are also lines that conflict with some patterns.  These need to be ignored:

```
722190 141106/2300 1013.10 981.20 17.94 292.30 0.00 55.00
1.68 0.00 290.50 0.00 0.00 27.00
0.00 3.90 -1.70 0.06 0.02 17.44
11.63 0.00 0.00 0.00 1.00 18.20
-4.80 -26.00 -0.02 60.00 979.00 0.19
15.80
722190 141107/0000 1014.00 981.90 16.44 291.50 0.00 56.00
0.69 0.00 290.50 0.00 0.00 0.00
0.00 4.40 -2.00 0.02 0.02 15.74
9.01 0.00 0.00 0.00 1.00 19.60
-5.50 -104.50 -0.04 60.00 951.30 20.00
11.94
```

Comment: Are there always 2 columns in 2nd continuing line as shown in your example?

Comment: @anubhava yes but I'd like regex to pull out both lines each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to capture each line separately using `MULTILINE` flag:

```
^((?:-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s+){9}-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?=\r?\n|\z)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/pS0uC3/4)

Once lines separated out you can just use `String#split` by space to get individual cell values.

Comment: We're getting close.  There seems to be some rows at the bottom I want to ignore but this pattern is picking it up (I know, I'm sorry , I should have included those.

Comment: Here is the file: http://www.meteor.iastate.edu/~ckarsten/bufkit/data/nam/nam_katl.buf

Comment: everything below: STN YYMMDD/HHMM PMSL PRES SKTC STC1 SNFL WTNS

Comment: Nope, it's still picking those up

Answer (score 1):

Updated:
based on the data posted, use this pattern w/ `gm` options

```
^((?:-?\d+(?:\.\d+)? ){7}(?:-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\r?\n))(?:-?\d+(?:\.\d+)? )(?:-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\r?\n|$)))
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/97)

Comment: For some reason, I see how nicely that works in the regex101 engine but in java, it doesn't match anything

Comment: @JamieMcIlroy updated my pattern above, hope it helps